# CSS can't seem to get rid of default border

Tags: css

so I have 1 input type text field, and I have like `5px border-radius` to it, but I can't seem to get rid of the default highlight border which is white. 
Even though the input field is a bit round at the edges, the default border is still rectangular, any idea how I can remove it ? thank you.

```
<input type="text" name="username" id="usrinput" size="36" value="Username" style="color:rgba(102,102,102,0.3);font-family: 'Lucida Sans Unicode', 'Lucida Grande', sans-serif;font-weight:600;" />
```

CSS:

```
#usrinput
{
    /*border:1px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.5);*/
    border:none;
    height:32px;
    border-radius:5px;
    outline:1px solid rgba(255,255,255,0.2);
    padding-left:10px;
    padding-right:10px;
}
```

Comment: can you share your code?

Comment: please show us the full source (CSS and HTML) in order for us to help diagnose.

Comment: I have made and edit , there is the source code.

Comment: Oh , I have seen the error , it's because of the outline, thank you for the help:)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're seeing the outline, not the border.

Use:

```
 outline:none;
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps you.

HTML:

```
<input type="text" name="username" class="input" />
```

CSS:

```
.input{
    border:1px solid #000;
    width:200px;
    height:30px;
}
```

You can customize the class also.